# MS SQL - how to take certain data out of tables based on ID of another table

Tags: sql

Really struggling to combine two tables in a certain way.

```
<Table1>
<Name> <job> <wage> <gender>
Bob   Fireman   500    0

<Table2>
<id> <desc>
0    Male
```

Trying to query so it displays as

```
Bob Fireman Male
```

So basically match on ID but display desc from another column.

Comment: Look up `inner join` in the documentation (or Google it).

Comment: Select name + job + desc from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.id

Comment: @RADAR That wouldn't work so good would it? Might want to join on `Table1.gender = Table2.id` instead...

Comment: @jpw, just a guess as I thought OP wants to concat, only works in SQL server

Comment: Your tables conception is not helpful. There is no solution for your question

Comment: @RADAR My objection wasn't against the concat, but joining on the wrong fields ;)

Comment: @Begueradj What do you mean? The table design is clear enough (and you did post the correct answer).

Comment: @jpw at least the conception is too confusing: `table2.id` sounds there will be  more than 2 entries.

Comment: There will be more entries, I assumed this was obvious. I believe Paul answer is correct, minus the where statement.

Comment: If your question reflects your real data (not a made-up example), adding a table to look up gender is needless, just store store the gender string directly with the person and use either a CHECK constraint or a table with *only* the gender string to ensure that only allowed values are added.  The indirection of an integer key is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to `INNER JOIN` the tables together.  Try this:

```
select [Name], [job], [Table2].[desc]
from [Table1]
inner join [Table2] on [id] = [gender]
where [Table1].[Name] = 'Bob'
```

You can use the `WHERE` clause to limit to a specific row.  If you want all the rows, then remove the `WHERE` clause.